# Can a registrar take back a domain name after you have purchased it?

Tags: domains, cctld

I recently purchased 2 ccTLD domains names. I got the receipts and the domains were confirmed in my account. Four days later, they were removed from the account. According to tech supports, the sales team went through my account and deemed the 2 domains were premium and took them back. This was not system error.

From my past experience, when I click "complete purchase", I would get a message on the receipt page saying "some domains were removed from your cart because they weren't available for sale." This is perfectly fine with me as I didn't pay for the domain.

My question is, can domains be taken back after they are sold?

Comment: What does the contract says? The agreement you had to agree with before being able to purchase the domain? In the domain name world you will often find clauses, in both registry contracts (included as a reference) and registrar contracts, that basically permits things like you experienced. For example in one: "You acknowledge and agree that XXXXX and registry reserve the right to deny, cancel or transfer any registration or transaction" ... "(ii) to protect the integrity and stability of, and correct mistakes made by, any domain name registry or registrar,".

Comment: You did not give details. premiums in ccTLDs are rare, at least at registry level. You may ask the registry directly if what happened to you is still in line with registrar obligations to the registry.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek I'm not sure of the agreement but I can imagined it's contains the clause you've stated. The 2 domains are both emoji domains. Which makes it even more dubious with regard to their premium status.

Comment: So `.ws` then probably? Then here it is kind of the exception of the rule (but also `.ws` is not really marketed as ccTLD even if it is technically): see https://www.website.ws/released.dhtml you have premiums, and this is the registry website...

Comment: *I'm not sure of the agreement *  go back to the registrar, and start reading it now :-) Note that, unfortunately, almost all registrars will have the exact same clauses or for the same effects.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the link and your replies. The domains were .ws and .ws. I think I need to do more research on this. I will post any findings here as I believe they may be helpful to the community. Cheers.